# How to maintain consistent Qt styling across platforms?

Tags: macos, qt, cross-platform

I'm writing a Qt application which is going to be initially deployed on Mac and Linux. I'm developing in Linux, so I'm able to spend all the time I need making sure that all the widgets and layouts are exactly how I want them to be. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get my hands on a Mac for development for any extended period of time. There's a lot of instances where widgets and layouts need minor (and sometimes major) tweaking to look good on Mac. Short of building a Mac-specific UI or using platform detection, how can I make this easier on myself? The biggest problems I run into are things like font size, spacing between widgets, and alignment of widgets. Any tips? I thought for sure there'd be a styling guide for Qt, but maybe I'm just asking the wrong questions.

Comment: Are you using style sheets? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote something very similar as an answer to question about CSS. But in general it's really depends how extensive your user interface. IS it really on a level where 'every pixel matters' or you can live with some small issues?

QT itself does a lot of job to make your interface looks the same, as well you even have features like CSS to make application looks indeed same way on different platforms independently on how native controls looks like.

This can be a really interesting approach for some fancy utility, but if we are talking about complex desktop application I strongly believe that keeping user to native controls as much as possible is a really right way to go (considering user experience, how well application fits in arounds etc)..

And thats where problem starts. Unfortunately the way Qt layout managers works on Linux/MacOSX/Win32 is not exactly the same. Some times there are obvious bugs on some platforms, like for example counting width of layout itself as '1', which is totally wrong.

Same applied for controls boundingRects, you are also completely right mentioning fonts etc.

I will try to summarise way how you can solve it (from my experience). Would be more then happy if experienced Qt developers will join, so we can make some kind of WiKi out of it, because it's very interesting and common question.

1) Use UILoaders and/or different set of UIs per platform.

I tend to use dynamic UI loading rather then statically compiled-in already for quite a while. It has several reasons like keeping views and controller classes separately, ability to deliver 'special' versions with just changing a set of UI files, etc.. One of the point is that by making UI files per platform you can tune them up taking in consideration all platform specifics and get really well looking interface. You can do same thing with static UI by conditions in .pro files.

2) Make interface 'wide' enough to hide visible changes. I am not sure if 'wide' is a right word but, an idea that you don't push Qt into the limits where you start to notice a lot of differences in UI, mostly it means that you keep your forms/dialogs fairly simple with enough space between components. That has a one big drawback - every UI will take in general more space (in sense of boundingRect) which it could if done carefully per platform.

3) CSS usage.. I honestly dont't no.. I saw couple of very nice projects where CSS really does a job, but it's still separated CSS for each platform and sometimes really complicated/conditional due to fact that same controls in different layouts requires different styling.